# How to set max-swallow-size in spring boot 2?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, bad-gateway

I'm trying to set **max-swallow-size** property of tomcat to -1 in springboot microservice while upgrading to springboot version 2; my earlier code was working but in upgrade some classes have changed so it stopped working.

I tried to set property in two ways but both are not working;

1. with service configuration

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainerFactory() {

        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();

        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector connector) {
                if(connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {
                    logger.debug("Setting maxSwallowSize for server connector as "+maxSwallowSize);
                    ((AbstractHttp11Protocol <?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(maxSwallowSize);
                }
            }
        });

        return factory;
    }
```

In control flow, I can see the debug line printed but it have not taken effect as end -point response is 502(Bad gateway) instead of 400

Second way : 
2. through application.properties file with property

```
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=-1
```

This is also not honored.

Now, How can I verify the property value whether it is actually set or not ?
or Am I setting the value in correct way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This New class has resolved my issue

```
@Component
public class TomcatCustomizer implements
WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {

        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector connector) {
                if(connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {
                    ((AbstractHttp11Protocol <?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(maxSwallowSize);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and I have used updated properties in spring boot 2.0

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size= XX MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size= YY MB
```